# Has anyone attempted to automate some of the editing process? Specifically to style everyday text towards poetry?

Tags: editing

Some translations surpass the original texts, thanks to the translator.

Can a text become more poetic by being re-written into more beautiful language by an open-source algorithm? The algorithm could be tweaked and improved by poetry-lovers and writers, and would function as an editor.

A mundane text (ie a recipe) could more closely resemble poetry after such a process. Then a final editing stage could be done with care and attention by a human. Such a tool could encourage non-writers into a creative editing process, by doing some of their work for them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with writing.

Comment: Read here and learn about the current state of the art of computer poetry: http://motherboard.vice.com/read/how-machines-write-poetry

Answer (score 3):

Poetry isn't a language or dialect - it's a form that something takes. It is something can't be "translated" in the sense that you are talking about.